# Drupal 6 - hook theme_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) is called many times

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

for some reason this function is being called many times each time i refresh the page, and therefore renders the page multiple times. This causes long loading time (the function includes calls to DB), how can i reduce the calls to this function to minimum?
Thanks.

Comment: It is normal for hook functions in Drupal to be called multiple times – that’s how the system _works_. Either find a more specific hook, or look at the parameters passed to it to make it only _do_ something when required (and do nothing on all other calls).

Comment: Ok, so which hook can i use to set the template variables just once? tnks

Comment: I found out that the hook is being called by other hooks for no reason, which caused unnecessary runs of the function. The solution i found was using the same hook as before, but with a check at the start who is the calling hook - 
if ($hook == "block" || $hook == "views_view_fields" || $hook == "views_view_unformatted" || $hook == "views_view" || $hook == "lead_form" || $hook == "page")) {
    return;
  }

Answer (score 0):

`template_preprocess` is called for every single template. Limit the number of calls by using a more specific hook, e.g. [`template_preprocess_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6), [`template_preprocess_node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6) or [`template_preprocess_block`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_block/6).